# Reindexing a dataframe using a time series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

I have a dataframe (df) that has a variabe called "date" that I index using the following code:

```
idx = df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(data=df.date, freq='10min'))
df = idx.sum()
```

Because I have "holes" in my data that I want to fill with NaNs, I want to reindex this dataframe using the complete time series called ts:

```
print(ts)
```

array(['2014-08-19T00:00:00.000000000', '2014-08-19T00:10:00.000000000',
'2014-08-19T00:20:00.000000000', ...,
'2015-08-16T23:40:00.000000000', '2015-08-16T23:50:00.000000000',
'2015-08-17T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

To for the reindexing, I use the following code:

```
df = df.reindex(ts).copy()
```

but get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-160-2c1b1d883eb1> in <module>()
----> 1 bi = bi.reindex(index)

10 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/period.py in dt64arr_to_periodarr(data, freq, tz)
    952             data, freq = data._values, data.dt.freq
    953 
--> 954     freq = Period._maybe_convert_freq(freq)
    955 
    956     if isinstance(data, (ABCIndexClass, ABCSeries)):

pandas/_libs/tslibs/period.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.period._Period._maybe_convert_freq()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'n'
```

Can someone explain to me why I am getting this message? Thanks

here is a chunk of the df:

```
date                      aa      bb      cc                                       
2014-08-19 00:00         781   9.798   9.289  
2014-08-19 00:10         782  10.004   9.382  
2014-08-19 00:20         783   9.832   9.434  
2014-08-19 00:30         784  10.019   9.593  
2014-08-19 00:40         785  10.087  10.028
```

Comment: Can you post the df so we can run it as well

Comment: done. thanks for your interest in my question!

Answer (score 0):

Using `DatetimeIndex` should work.

`PeriodIndex` is for `timespan` but here we are dealing with `timestamps`.

We were getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'n'` because we were trying to reindex the ts with `PeriodIndex`.

**Code**

```
idx = df.groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(data=df.date, freq='10min'))
df = idx.sum()

ts=['2014-08-19T00:00:00.000000000', '2014-08-19T00:10:00.000000000', '2014-08-19T00:20:00.000000000', '2015-08-16T23:40:00.000000000', '2015-08-16T23:50:00.000000000', '2015-08-17T00:00:00.000000000']
ts=pd.DatetimeIndex(ts)

df.reindex(ts)
```

**Output**

```
                    aa      bb      cc
2014-08-19 00:00:00 781.0   9.798   9.289
2014-08-19 00:10:00 782.0   10.004  9.382
2014-08-19 00:20:00 783.0   9.832   9.434
2015-08-16 23:40:00 NaN NaN NaN
2015-08-16 23:50:00 NaN NaN NaN
2015-08-17 00:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Have you replaced PeriodIndex from both places i.e idx and ts. It is not possible to get same error because now you are not using 'PeriodIndex' now and the error is for period `freq = Period._maybe_convert_freq(freq)`

Comment: it comes from the fact that the is no frequency attached to the index :

Comment: DatetimeIndex(['2014-08-19 00:00:00', '2014-08-19 00:10:00',
               '2014-08-19 00:20:00', '2014-08-19 00:30:00',
               '2014-08-19 00:40:00', '2014-08-19 00:50:00'
               ...
               '2015-08-16 22:30:00', '2015-08-16 22:40:00',
               '2015-08-16 22:50:00', '2015-08-16 23:00:00',
               '2015-08-16 23:10:00', '2015-08-16 23:20:00',
               '2015-08-16 23:30:00', '2015-08-16 23:40:00',
               '2015-08-16 23:50:00', '2015-08-17 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=13393, freq=None)

Comment: Can you plz paste you complete code in the question.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/33358 
Also, freq will always be None if the elements of DTI are not evenly spaced.